# Can two apps written in different languages communicate?

Tags: java, android, c, sockets

I want to write a mobile app (Android) in Java and have it communicate with a google chrome extension. In order to do this I need to use a socket to send data to the mobile device. This can't be done in JavaScript obviously so I looked into the [Native Client](http://developers.google.com/native-client/overview) compiler which would allow me to use C (Java not supported) to create the socket. The app needs to be written in java. At this point this is all theoretical since I don't know C or Java. I do, however, have some programming experience and am willing to learn these two languages. I don't have any experince at all with sockets.

My question is this, Can I initiate a socket using C and have it send data to an app using Java?

Comment: "Send data between languages"? Does that even *mean* anything?

Comment: I couldn't think of a good way to word it, sorry. The new title is a bit more sensible :-).

Comment: The apps at either end of the socket have no idea about each other, unless you choose to send that data as part of the message.  You could replace one app with another written in a new language and provided it handled the data in the same way, everything would just keep on working.  I have web services (which are ultimately just software listening to a socket) serving clients written in Java, Objective C and C#.  But as Kerrek SB said, the language has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many *Communication protocols*.  As implied, *protocol* suggests a standard interface.  Its the standard interface part that guarantees `apps written in different languages can communicate`.  Stated differently, an application written in any "language" that can package up some data, and send it according to the rules of a particular protocol, can successfully send and/or receive data from a program of a *different* language, but recognizing the same protocol.  TCP/IP, for example, is a protocol that allows an application written in one language to send and receive byte data in a way that is ***recognized*** by applications written in a different language.  It uses well defined and documented common interfaces (eg. IPv4 or IPv6), and is frequently used as a method of communication between applications written in different languages.  Routines that use TCP/IP protocols are written in languages such as C, C++, C#, Java and others.  These languages (and most other modern languages) have libraries available that simplify and further standardize implementation within applications that ***talk*** TCP/IP.  Sockets, for example, is a (perhaps *the*) dominant method used in applications providing internet connectivity.  Sockets libraries are available for languages native to both ***[Linux](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)*** and ***[Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737889%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***.

Answer (score 3):

> Can two apps written in different languages communicate?

Of course, they can! Just express communication data in some universal exchange format like JSON, YAML or XML and it will be easy readable on almost any platform/language. Binary data is good too, but communicating with it you should know and respect things like alignment and endianness.

NOTE: Javascript can use sockets! You can search term AJAX to know more.

Comment: When you refer to AJAX sockets is this what you mean? http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp And is it possible or logical to use this to send data to a mobile app? What kind of programming would be required on the app side?

Comment: It is quite logical to use AJAX on web page to communicate with any server. If your mobile app has *server* socket, you can connect to it and talk to your app from a browser page. But notice that `XMLHttpRequest` has big limitation - it allow connections only within the same domain that is in page's address. To overcome this limitation you can use JSONP, [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) library or etc.

Comment: And... *browser extensions* are not subject to the same origin policy (extension JS can query any domain)

Answer (score 2):

> Can I initiate a socket using C and have it send data to an app using Java?

Um, sure. For example, it is unlikely that the Web browser that you are using being written in the same programming language as the Web server you are visiting. That's in part because several languages are usually involved in each side.